# SKPhysicsContact crash - Bad Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, flappy-bird-clone

Ok, so I'm quite confused. I set my viewcontroller as the delegate for the physicsworld. When my Flappy Bird collides with a coin, this method gets run:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
if (contact != nil && contact.bodyA != nil){
    if (coinsArray.count > 0)
    {
        if (contact.bodyA.mass == 0) {
            [contact.bodyA.node removeAllActions];
            [coinsArray removeObject:contact.bodyA.node];
            [contact.bodyA.node removeFromParent];
            savedData.coins++;
        }
    }
}}
```

So this doesn't make sense to me because SOMETIMES I get a badaccess call when my bird touches the coin, but like 95% of the time, it works as expected. The only times that coins are being deleted from the scene is when a bird touches the coin, or when the coin.position.x < (0.5 * coin.size.width);

Not sure why I'm getting badaccess, especially since I wrote if (contact != nil && contact.bodyA != nil). Plus, why would I even get bad access when there is a delegate calling out to say 'Hey! run this method with this SKPhysicsContact'?

Any help from anyone?

Comment: Try using your scene instead as delegate, simply because it has the same lifetime as the physics world attached to the scene. Secondly removeAllActions is superfluous here since you're going to remove the node from its parent anyway.

Comment: Okay, I fixed this problem. Turns out that one of the contact bodies turned out to be the scene's physicsbody, which is just a rectangle that is wider than the screen in both directions, but just as tall. Occassionally I think that an object wouldn't be deleted when it went off screen and a contact was made between that object and the scene's bounds. I was trying to call contact.bodyA.mass, but there is no mass. So it was crashing because of that.